# Trim function not working properly, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: excel, vba

**Background:** At work a client has an issue with an Excel Macro they have been using for a long time now. In short, the macro reads .txt files, trims away rows that don't include the value "22300" in column A (starting beneath the word "Rekening") adds a total value of the numbers associated with the remaining rows and generates an Excel file of the results.

**Current results:** After a change of the provided .txt files template (minor changes) the macro has stopped working. When the user starts the macro (by clicking on an image/shape) the macro starts running but gives a 1004 error (windowed error). When the user clicks on OK the Macro continuous generating the Excel file though without applying the trim function and adding the total value.

I have double checked the spelling of "Rekening" and "22300" within the files. Besides that I also tried playing with the Offset values though again, I am not sure what I am doing since I am pretty new to this.

```
Option Explicit
Sub OpenBestand()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim sBronMap As String
    Dim sResultmap As String
    Dim sDonemap As String
    Dim sBronbest As String
    Dim wbBron As Workbook

    On Error GoTo Errorhandler

    sBronMap = Blad1.Range("Bronmap").Value
    If Right(sBronMap, 1) <> "\" Then sBronMap = sBronMap & "\"

    sBronbest = Dir(sBronMap & "*.prt", vbNormal)
    If sBronbest = "" Then
        sBronbest = Dir(sBronMap & "*.txt", vbNormal)
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If sBronbest <> "" Then
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = False
            .StatusBar = "Even geduld bezig met verwerken bestand " & sBronbest
        End With

        Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=sBronMap & sBronbest, _
            Origin:=xlWindows, _
            StartRow:=9, _
            DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
            FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), _
                            Array(9, 1), _
                            Array(18, 1), _
                            Array(33, 1), _
                            Array(53, 1), _
                            Array(69, 2), _
                            Array(78, 1), _
                            Array(88, 1), _
                            Array(95, 1), _
                            Array(109, 1), _
                            Array(123, 1), _
                            Array(129, 1)), _
                            TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

        Set wbBron = ActiveWorkbook
        Bewerkbestand wbBron

    Else
        MsgBox "geen bestand gevonden", vbInformation, "Mededeling"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    sResultmap = Blad1.Range("Resultmap").Value
    If Right(sResultmap, 1) <> "\" Then sResultmap = sResultmap & "\"
    wbBron.SaveAs sResultmap & Left(wbBron.Name, InStr(1, wbBron.Name, ".") - 1), xlWorkbookNormal

    sDonemap = Blad1.Range("Donemap").Value
    If Right(sDonemap, 1) <> "\" Then sDonemap = sDonemap & "\"

    FileCopy sBronMap & sBronbest, sDonemap & sBronbest
    Kill sBronMap & sBronbest

    wbBron.Activate
    With ActiveWindow
        .ScrollColumn = 1
        .ScrollRow = 1
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .StatusBar = False
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
Exit Sub
Errorhandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Fout tijdens verwerking!"
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .StatusBar = False
    End With
End Sub


Sub Bewerkbestand(ByVal wbBron As Workbook)
    On Error GoTo Errorhandler

    Dim contrCel As Range, StartCel As Range
    Dim TotBedr As Double

    TotBedr = 0
    Set contrCel = wbBron.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    Do While UCase(Trim(contrCel.Value)) <> "Rekening"
        Set contrCel = contrCel.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    Set StartCel = contrCel

    Set contrCel = contrCel.Offset(2, 0)
    Do While contrCel.Value & contrCel.Offset(1, 0).Value & contrCel.Offset(2, 0).Value <> ""
        If contrCel.Value <> "22300" Then
            Set contrCel = contrCel.Offset(-1, 0)
            contrCel.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
        End If
        Set contrCel = contrCel.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    'Bedragen optellen
    Set contrCel = StartCel.Offset(2, 0)
    Do While contrCel.Value <> ""
        TotBedr = TotBedr + CDbl(contrCel.Offset(0, 9).Value)
        Set contrCel = contrCel.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    With StartCel
        .Offset(-2, 8).Value = "Totaalbedrag"
        .Offset(-2, 8).Font.Bold = True
        .Offset(-2, 8).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .Offset(-2, 9).Value = TotBedr
        .Offset(-2, 9).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 16
        .Offset(-2, 9).Font.Bold = True
    End With

Exit Sub

Errorhandler:
MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Fout tijdens verwerking!"

End Sub
```

I have included a screenshot of the input and desired/previously generated output.

Input screenshot

[image: Input screenshot]

Desired/previously generated output

[image: Desired/previously generated output]

Here is the content (edited obviously) of a txt file for reference:

```
    A(s0V&k0V&l0o8V(s12.66A                                     G X X X X E E E K   V E E E E E K I I I I R E E E E E G

=================================================================================================================================
 Integr.bestand:  MEMO      Periode:     Dagb:  Soci Zac Stap                                     Bladnr:    1

=================================================================================================================================
Rekening     Kostenpl. Kostendr. Rekeningnaam        Omschrijving    Boekstuk Datum     Periode         Debet        Credit
=================================================================================================================================
 RUNPARAMETERS
 GEBRUIKER   : Gxx
 Gemo    : 001
 Financiele integratie Kup
 Periode             : 201907
 Verslagnummer van   : 180000
 Verslagnummer t/m   : 180022
 Periode             : 201907
 Regeling(en)        : 0 Regeling 1
                       1 Regeling 2
                       2 Regeling 3
                       3 Regeling 4
                       4 Regeling 5
                       5 Regeling 6
                       6 Regeling 7
                       7 Regeling 8
                       8 Regeling 9
                       9 Regeling 10
                       10 Regeling 11
                       11 Regeling 12
                       12 Regeling 13
                       13 Regeling 14
 Boekingsdatum van   : --
 Boekingsdatum t/m   : --
 EINDE RUNPARAMETERS
                                     G X X X X E E E K   V E E E E E K I I I I R E E E E E G

=================================================================================================================================
 Integr.bestand:  MEMO      Periode:     Dagb:  Soci Zac Stap                                     Bladnr:    2

=================================================================================================================================
Rekening     Kostenpl. Kostendr. Rekeningnaam        Omschrijving    Boekstuk Datum     Periode         Debet        Credit
=================================================================================================================================
 60XXXXXX    4XXXX               NXXXXXXXXXXX        PXXX            0XXXXXXX 30-07-2019 201906       1XX,XX
 60XXXXXX    4XXXX               IXXXXXXXX           PXXX            0XXXXXXX 30-07-2019 201906                      7X,XX
 60XXXXXX    4XXXX               OXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX   PXXX            0XXXXXXX 30-07-2019 201906                    8XXX,XX
    22300                        BXXXXXXX            PXXX            0XXXXXXX 30-07-2019 201906                    3XXX,XX
 60XXXXXX    4XXXX               EXXXXXXXXXX         PXXX            0XXXXXXX 30-07-2019 201906      6XXX,XX
    22304                        AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX PXXX            0XXXXXXX 30-07-2019 201906                    6XXX,XX
 60XXXXXX    4XXXX               VXXXXXXXXXXX        PXXX            0XXXXXXX 30-07-2019 201906       5XX,13
 60XXXXXX    4XXXX               RXXXXXXXXXXXXX      PXXX            0XXXXXXX 30-07-2019 201906                     5XX,XX
 60XXXXXX    4XXXX               LXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX PXXX            0XXXXXXX 30-07-2019 201906     1XXXX,XX

                                                                                                ------------- -------------
Totalen :                                                                                           4XXX,XX      4XXX,XX
                                                                                                ============= =============
```

Comment: Is the `Exit Sub` in the end a typo that should be `End Sub`? • Please explain what you mean by *"Both the trim function and print function ('Bedragen optellen') aren't showing."* • It is pretty unclear what your actual issue is. *"Not working"* is no useful error description.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! The End sub comes a bit later. In between there is an Errorhandler.

If you want I can paste the entire macro to get a better view.

Comment: Actually the other points I mentioned are much more improtant, because your question is unclear. Please [edit] and improve it. We need to know what exactly the issue is, where do you get errors and which, or what does your code vs what did you expect. Example input/output, screenshots everything you can provide to explain can help. Reading [mcve] might help you. • And yes if there is an error handler please show that too.

Comment: OK, I guess finding the issue is impossible without providing a proper example of the text file, because we need to reproduce the issue (anything else would be guessing). Also we need to know where the error occurs.

Comment: Updated the OP with the contents of a input file. Note that numbers have been recplaced with "X" and words have been changed for privacy reasons.

Thanks again for the replies Peh, much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is in this line

```
Do While UCase(Trim(contrCel.Value)) <> "Rekening"
```

you are looking for the `UCase` of a cell value that means all characters in the cell value are converted to upper case by `UCase` so when it comes to `Rekening` you compare `"REKENING" <> "Rekening"` so it does not match. You would need to change it to

```
Do While UCase(Trim(contrCel.Value)) <> "REKENING"
```

But instead I recommend to use the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find) which should find `"Rekening"` faster than a loop. You can make it non case sensitive `MatchCase:=False` and let it look at a part of a cell `LookAt:=xlPart` so you don't need to `Trim`.

```
Set StartCel = wbBron.Worksheets(1).Columns("A").Find(What:="Rekening", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
```

See the complete improved code of the `Bewerkbestand` procedure below:

```
Sub Bewerkbestand(ByVal wbBron As Workbook)
    On Error GoTo Errorhandler

    Dim StartCel As Range
    Set StartCel = wbBron.Worksheets(1).Columns("A").Find(What:="Rekening", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)

    If StartCel Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "'Rekening' could not be found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim contrCel As Range
    Set contrCel = StartCel.Offset(2, 0)
    Do While contrCel.Value & contrCel.Offset(1, 0).Value & contrCel.Offset(2, 0).Value <> ""
        If contrCel.Value <> "22300" Then
            Set contrCel = contrCel.Offset(-1, 0)
            contrCel.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
        End If
        Set contrCel = contrCel.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    'Bedragen optellen
    Set contrCel = StartCel.Offset(2, 0)

    Dim TotBedr As Double
    Do While contrCel.Value <> ""
        TotBedr = TotBedr + CDbl(contrCel.Offset(0, 9).Value)
        Set contrCel = contrCel.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    With StartCel
        .Offset(-2, 8).Value = "Totaalbedrag"
        .Offset(-2, 8).Font.Bold = True
        .Offset(-2, 8).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .Offset(-2, 9).Value = TotBedr
        .Offset(-2, 9).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 16
        .Offset(-2, 9).Font.Bold = True
    End With


    Exit Sub
Errorhandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Fout tijdens verwerking!"
End Sub
```

Comment: You sir, are my hero!

Many thanks for solution and a more efficient function.
Besides that, big thanks for the fast response